# How do you make a function use 3 different variables one at a time?

Tags: c++

Not really sure how do you make a function run 3 variables one at a time.

Comment: What do you mean by "another function called 'classify'?"

Comment: "Not really sure how do you make a function run 3 variables one at a time" - me neither. What's meant by "running a variable"?

Comment: Your syntax with your logical ORs is completely off.  You always have to compare the variable to something, e.g. `if (a == 200 || b == 200 || c == 200).  You can't just group `(a || b || c == 200)`

Comment: That's not at all how boolean operators work. `a || b == 200` is equivalent to `(a) || (b == 200)`, **not** `(a == 200) || (b == 200)`.

Comment: Yet another "minimal understanding" question for today... >.<

Comment: What do you want to happen when you call the function? `ratescore(750, 200, 250)`

Comment: Then you want to call the function 3 times. ratescore(750); ratescore(200); ratescore(250); Check Arkadiy's answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're trying to write something like

```
void ratescore(int value)
{
  if (value  == 200)   {
    cout << "200 is exactly 200" << endl;
  }
 // and so on
}

void ratescore (int a, int b, int c)   {
   ratescore(a);
   ratescore(b);
   ratescore(c);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You will have to make a compare guard for all three values.

```
if (a == 200 || b == 200 || c == 200) {
    /* Do something */
}
```